# Android WebView - does it support digest authentication?

Tags: android, android-webview

I think the title is self explanatory. I can't find any resources or references that mention that digest authentication is supported in WebViews.

A couple of caveats:

- I'm not talking about basic authentication where the authorisation header is sent with base64 encoding.
- I'm only talking about WebViews embedded in an application, not simple http requests where apache http client can be used for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set one WebViewClient in your WebView and override below method in your WebViewClient, see below code..

```
private class ExWebChromeClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}

webView.setWebViewClient(new ExWebChromeClient());//set your Extended WebViewClient here
```

Here you can show one auth dialog..See [showHttpAuthentication method from Android native Browser app](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/CallbackProxy.java#CallbackProxy.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest%28android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) here, here one http auth dialog is shown and handled properly inside WebView

Comment: I do not understand this answer fully. When onReceivedHttpAuthRequest is called in my code (the overridden one), then I will call super.OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest? What would that do? How will the digest authentication be handled?

Comment: do you want to show username / password dialog ? or bypass auth dialog and set username/password in background and proceed?

Comment: Bypass the dialog and hardcode the credentials. Never mind though, I found that httpauthhandler.proceed(username,password) does work with digest authentication transparently, without any more changes!

Comment: cool.. you must be calling that in onReceivedHttpAuthRequest.. right? or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, inside onReceivedHttpAuthRequest :-). Although that means that always the first request doesnt have any credentials and fails, and then the 401 code is handled by my code and the credentials are added using proceed(). Any way to succeed in the first request?

Comment: not sure why it is failing in first attempt.. it should succeed in first attempt .Anyway u can accept my answer ;) if u found it helpfull..

Comment: The problem is that onReceivedHttpAuthRequest (and thus proceed() ) is only called when there is a failure. The first request going forward to the server does not have an authorization header at all.

Comment: For anyone having issues, just write this line `handler.proceed(mUsername, mPassword);` in the overridden `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()`. Make sure you don't call the `super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()` because my understanding is that it cancels the request.

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me:

```
webView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("domain", "realm", "username", "password");
webView.loadUrl("http://domain:port/url/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setHttpAuthUsernamePassword](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setHttpAuthUsernamePassword%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the `WebView` to specify the username and password to use. It's used for basic and digest authentication requests.

Comment: Thank you @Haelty. Are you absolutely sure about that though? I have tried it, but it doesn't seem like it's working.

Comment: It seems that the only thing this method does is to store the credentials in a sqlite db. Nothing more, even for basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

In one word, it does support HTTP digest authentication. I have tested and sure about it.